# Why does my java program report "package not found" when it's clearly there in the classpath?

Tags: java, neo4j, classpath

My kick-off of a new java application that imports a third-party java package has stalled right out of the gate.  The compiler is reporting that the package in question does not exist.  Although I began with VS Code and Gradle, I've simplified the problem down to just the java app code, the third-party jar file, and the javac compiler command.  Can someone please help me figure out why javac is reporting "package not present" for a jar file that seems clearly to be right there in the classpath?

Here's the command line:

```
javac -verbose -classpath . App.java
```

Here's the java version:

```
javac 17.0.1
```

Here's the directory listing:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kevin kevin   1059 Feb  6 12:08 App.java
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kevin kevin 212231 Feb  5 17:14 neo4j-4.4.3.jar
```

Here's the App.java code:

```
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package neural;

import org.neo4j.*;

public class App {
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
    private static void registerShutdownHook( final DatabaseManagementService managementService )
    {
        // Registers a shutdown hook for the Neo4j instance so that it
        // shuts down nicely when the VM exits (even if you "Ctrl-C" the
        // running application).
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                managementService.shutdown();
            }
        } );
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new App().getGreeting());

        managementService = new DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder( databaseDirectory ).build();
        graphDb = managementService.database( DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME );
        registerShutdownHook( managementService );

        managementService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Here's the start of the errors:

```
App.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    private static void registerShutdownHook( final DatabaseManagementService managementService )
                                                    ^
  symbol:   class DatabaseManagementService
  location: class App
App.java:6: error: package org.neo4j does not exist
import org.neo4j.*;
^
```

Here's confirmation it's looking in the current directory:

```
[search path for source files: .]
[search path for class files: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/lib/modules,.]
```

Here's an exerpt from the jar file:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/
META-INF/services/
org/
org/neo4j/
org/neo4j/graphdb/
org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/
org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/module/
org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/module/id/
org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/module/edition/
org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/module/edition/context/
org/neo4j/graphdb/facade/
org/neo4j/server/
org/neo4j/server/startup/
org/neo4j/dbms/
org/neo4j/dbms/identity/
org/neo4j/dbms/systemgraph/
org/neo4j/dbms/systemgraph/versions/
org/neo4j/dbms/procedures/
org/neo4j/dbms/api/
org/neo4j/dbms/database/
org/neo4j/dbms/database/readonly/
```

I've rerun (and since renamed some files for other reasons):

```
javac -verbose -classpath neo4j-4.4.3.jar /home/kevin/Projects/echo_ws/lib_neo4j/lib_neo4j/src/main/java/lib_neo4j/lib_neo4j.java
```

which gives

```
[search path for source files: neo4j-4.4.3.jar]
[search path for class files: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/lib/modules,neo4j-4.4.3.jar]
[loading /modules/java.base/java/lang/Object.class]
[loading /modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class]
/home/kevin/Projects/echo_ws/lib_neo4j/lib_neo4j/src/main/java/lib_neo4j/lib_neo4j.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    private static void registerShutdownHook( final DatabaseManagementService managementService )
                                                    ^
  symbol:   class DatabaseManagementService
  location: class lib_neo4j
/home/kevin/Projects/echo_ws/lib_neo4j/lib_neo4j/src/main/java/lib_neo4j/lib_neo4j.java:6: error: package org.neo4j does not exist
import org.neo4j.*;
^
```

Comment: `-classpath .` doesn't include JAR files located in `.`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
javac -verbose -classpath ./* App.java
```

But I would strongly recommend to use building systems like `Gradle` or `Maven`.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  The problem originated with the Gradle project I created with VS Code.  I simplified to this case to reduce the possible causes.  Unfortunately, your suggestion does not change the result.

Answer (score 0):

Java requires that every .java file (and every .class file) be located in a directory that exactly matches that class’s declared package.  Since your App class contains `package neural;`, you must place App.java in a `neural` subdirectory and you must compile it as `javac -verbose -classpath . neural/App.java`.

Your third-party .jar file should not be inside the `neural` directory.  Each .jar file must be an explicit classpath entry:

```
javac -verbose -classpath .:neo4j-4.4.3.jar neural/App.java
```

**Update:**

Your problem description has changed.  It now appears that neither the compile-time classpath nor your use of package-compliant directories is the problem.

It appears that the problem is simpler:  `import` statements ending with `*` do not cross package boundaries.  Different packages have no relationship to each other whatsoever, even when one is a prefix of the other.  A subpackage is not a “child” of the superpackage in any way, despite what appearances may imply.

This statement:

```
import org.neo4j.*;
```

only imports classes in the `org.neo4j` package.  It does not import classes in `org.neo4j.dbms` and it does not import classes in `org.neo4j.dbms.api`.

The latter is important, because [org.neo4j.dbms.api is where DatabaseManagementService is located.](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/4.2/javadocs/org/neo4j/dbms/api/DatabaseManagementService.html)  If you want to use that class, I suggest importing it explicitly:

```
import org.neo4j.dbms.api.DatabaseManagementService;
```

`import` statements ending with `*` are considered a bad practice.  Just import whatever you need explicitly, and you won’t have this problem again.

If you ever find that, without wildcard imports, you have too many `import` statements, it’s a sign that you probably should break up your class into smaller pieces.

Comment: I think your answer is not correct for this situation. Because, you CAN COMPILE java class with `package neural;` but not in `neural` folder. You can try. The question is about compiling.

Comment: @user207421 Please, read the question. `The compiler is reporting that the package in question does not exist. `. And also pay attention to the first code snippet in the question.

Comment: I began all this with an explicit jar reference.

Comment: I actually started with explicit jar file list, instead of "." for the current folder.  I've modified my description above to show that the problem exists for directly referencing the jar file too.

Comment: @SKRogers Updated my answer.